# Wordpress - show downloads counter in the homepage for the posts separately

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

I am using WordPress 4.4.1 with grid system for displaying all the posts on the homepage, I am using [Simple download monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-download-monitor/) plugin its working fine the inside of the posts.Now I want to show downloads counter for each post in the homepage.

```
 $db_count = sdm_get_download_count_for_post($id); echo $db_count;
```

I tried using this to display but the counter shows 0

Please share your ideas where I did wrong. Thanks....

Comment: you getting $id value in the home page?

Comment: @RahulS s thanks for replying, Nope i am not getting it :(

Comment: Please use the  post_id inside sdm_get_download_count_for_post($post_id);. Try to get post_id in that page

Comment: i need to get the sdm_downloads_id instead

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the following shortcode to show the download counter of
>   any of your files that you manage using this plugin:
>
> `[sdm-download-counter id="X"]` 
>   X is the ID of the downloadable file in
>   question.

You can find complete documentation from here. 
https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/simple-wordpress-download-monitor-plugin

Comment: Thanks Saleem , But i need to show it in the homepage where all the posts are displayed , there i can't use short code there